# Как перенаправить приложение из Android Emulator на свой ноутбук?

Tags: android, android-studio, клиент-сервер, dns, мобильная-разработка

Я разрабатываю мультиплатформенную игру (для браузера, Android, позже добавлю iOS) на своем Macbook Air и также изредка на другом компьютере с  Windows 7:

[image: скриншот макбука]

Пока я писал браузерную часть своей игры, все было удобно:

я запускал "development backend" состоящий из Jetty и PostgreSQL на макбуке и потом на нем же отлаживал игру в браузере, соединявшуюся к localhost.

Но теперь я перешел к разработке мобильного приложения и удобство закончилось:

при отладке в Android Emulator или на присоединенном через USB-кабель телефоне приходится использовать настоящий "production backend" на арендованном Linux-сервере (то есть в самолете или на поезде уже не попрограммируешь из-за отсутствия связи).

Мне кажется, это часто встречающаяся проблема - ведь многим приходится отлаживать мобильное приложение, связывающееся со скриптом через HTTP.

Поделитесь вашими стратегиями подобной отладки, как "подружить" Android Studio и "development backend" на одном ноутбуке?

Я пытался приспособить для своей цели dnsmasq (из коллекции brew), но пока в этом не особо преуспел.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, я нашел хорошее решение для своей проблемы:

Адрес **http://10.0.2.2** введенный в Android Emulator укажет как раз на мой ноутбук, как описано в документе [Set Up Android Emulator Networking](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html):

[image: screenshot]

Еще я получил предложение использовать [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) или взглянуть на `adb reverse`

Answer (score 1):

В случае телефона, подключённого по кабелю можно так: сажаете ноут и телефон на одну Wi-Fi сеть и приложение на телефоне коннектите к локальному IP ноутбука. В случае эмулятора, думаю, то же самое можно сделать (т.е. подключаться к локальному IP ноутбука).

Comment: Верно, но в самолёте так уже не получится

Comment: @AlexanderFarber, вполне получится. Раздаёте с ноута/телефона wi-fi, смотрите IP ноута и прописываете оный в приложении.